# Load two images or load one and modify it?

Tags: php, gd

My website is showing same image, one normal and other is blurred and I'm thinking what is better method of doing it in terms of speed. Create two images upon uploading where it uploads one normal image and one blurred to server or upload only one image but blur second one on the fly using gd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GD, I would do it at upload and save them as flat files.

Apache and other web servers can serve flat files remarkably fast.

However, I would look into using http://www.graphicsmagick.org/ to do the image manipulation. It's much, much faster and efficient than Imagemagick and most certainly PHP's GD.

Comment: Yeah, it is really, really slow. Blurring it 60 times takes about 30 seconds... =|

Comment: Sounds about right. I wouldn't go near GD. Definitely do it upon upload and use GraphicsMagick -- or at least ImageMagick.